# Format date time

Tags: c#, datetime

Hey there, I am extracting the date and time of creation of a file. the date should be 7/1/2010 2:08 PM but the format comes out as 2:08:07 01/07/2010 when called from my application. I would like it show as it does in the file explorer (7/1/2010 2:08 PM). How can I accomplish this?

```
    string createdOnCMM = Creationtime; //this returns the 2:08:07 01/07/2010 


// I think I need a modified verison of the following to reformat it

    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(createdOnCMM);
    String.Format("0:{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt);
```

Comment: What are you then doing to display the data?  Your format string looks right, so I can only assume the problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: Of course, hardcoding the date format is a really bad thing to do. Why not just use the system default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to format with your current culture's short date string then use the `g` specifier as mentioned in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166826/format-date-time/3166887#3166887).

If you need the exact format that you mentioned, regardless of your current culture, then one of the following should do the trick:

```
string formatted = dt.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm tt");

// or

string formatted = string.Format("{0:M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm tt}", dt);
```

Comment: this displays 1/7/2010 2:08:07PM ... i would really like it to be 7/1/2010 2:08:07PM

Comment: THANKS ... displays properly now.. it thinks that the 07 is the day when in reality that is actually July. but it displays correctly nontheless.

Comment: @jake: I just edited my format string back to its original, correct form (which, unfortunately, is giving you the undesired results). The problem is that the `DateTime` itself is incorrect. Your `Convert.ToDateTime` call is interpreting the day part of `createdOnCMM` as the month and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

Your compound format string isn't quite right. Try this:

```
string s = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt);
```

Alternatively, if you *only* want to format the `DateTime`, call ToString directly:

```
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

(That's a more readable approach, IMO.)

Note that this is very culture-specific at the moment. That *may* be okay for your intended use, but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

From [Microsoft's Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), you should be able to get what you want by using the `g` format string like the following:

```
String.Format("{0:g}", dateTimeValue);
```

That should yield the format you'd like.

Comment: As Jon mentioned, your format string needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: this displays 1/7/2010 2:08:07PM  ... i would really like it to be 7/1/2010 2:08:07PM

Comment: Yup, sorry--I didn't notice that.  Then using Jon's format string will yield what you want.  Notice that the '0:' is inside the curly braces.